# Mysql encryption/decryption without sending password in query

Tags: mysql, database, encryption

I need to encrypt some specific columns in mysql database. I researched and found few ways like AES_ENCRYPT functions, but these solutions requires sending the key value in the query.

I am looking for a solution where password can be stored in database some location and mysql can automatically use that value to encyrpt or decrypt that particular column?

Thank you.